# UISwitch changes cell when scrolling tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a weird problem (at least in my opinion). When I add a UISwitch to my table view, the switch changes cell automatically when the user scrolls the table view. Below is the code on how I create the UISwitch for the tableview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        //NSLog(@"This is what we are looking for %@    %@", checkUsername, checkPassword);
        // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array =[dictionary objectForKey:@"Settings"];
    NSString * cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryView = nil;


    if (!cell) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            //switcher.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"Settings"];

        if (section == 1)
        {

            UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
            cell.accessoryView = switchView;
            [switchView setOn:YES animated:NO];
            [switchView setTag:[indexPath row]];
            [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchWasChangedFromEnabled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                //[self.tableView reloadData];
            [switchView release];
        }

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Can someone please let me know why the switches keep moving out of the designated cells and also a possible remedy.

Justin Gallagher suggested this:

It's happening because you're cacheing your cells and reusing them. Sometimes the cell with the switch is getting reused in another place. Try setting a different identifier for the cell with the switch.

But can someone tell me how I can set different identifier for each cell?

Cheers,

iSee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you're cacheing your cells and reusing them.  Sometimes the cell with the switch is getting reused in another place. Try setting a different identifier for the cell with the switch.

Comment: NO.. it's not.. it's because the UISwitch is being initialised in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. so the UISwitch will reset itself back to the initial state. please declare your switchView variable in .h file, then initialise it during viewDidLoad, then add your switchView into your accessoryView.. that will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code presented [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10912-reusing-cells-increased-performance-adding-subviews-cells.html#post49090) [original source] to solve my issue. I have pasted the code snippet below. Also, this idea was given to me by Justin Gallagher. Thank You.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (<indexPath is for cell type "A">) {
    static NSString *SomeIdentifierA = @"SomeIdentifierA";

        // This could be some custom table cell class if appropriate    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SomeIdentifierA];
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SomeIdentifierA] autorelease];
            // Any other attributes of the cell that will never change for type "A" cells.
    }

        if (someCondition) {
            cell.textColor = <someColor>;
        } else {
            cell.textColor = <anotherColor>;
        }
        cell.text = <some text>;    
    return cell;
    } else if (<indexPath is for cell type "B") {
    static NSString *SomeIdentifierB = @"SomeIdentifierB";

        // This could be some custom table cell class if appropriate    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SomeIdentifierB];
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SomeIdentifierB] autorelease];
            // Any other attributes of the cell that will never change for type "B" cells.
    }

        cell.text = <some text>;    
    return cell;
    } else {
        return nil; // Oops - should never get here
```